# swfObject embeded object not working in ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, flash, swfobject

After a long day of searching on the web, i didn't find any solution to my problem.

I have a problem loading an swf file in my webPage using swfObject, doesn't work in IE11 ( works fine in ie8-10,  firefox and chrome)

Here's my context  :
This is the initialization of the params send to IE through the swfObject
`

```
// For version detection
var swfVersionStr = "10.0.0";

// To use express install, set to playerProductInstall.swf
var xiSwfUrlStr = "commun/swf/playerProductInstall.swf";

//FlashVars : contains an url used for an http request that returns  the crossdomain.xml file with the crossDomainPolicy...
var flashvars = {
    crossdomainURL : httpOrigin + "the.url.to.crossdomain.policy.file"
};

var params = {};
params.quality = "high";
params.bgcolor = "white";
params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
params.allowfullscreen = "true";
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "dematMultiuploader";
attributes.name = "dematMultiuploader";
attributes.align = "middle";
swfobject.embedSWF(
    "the/url/to/SWFfile.swf", "falshContentID", 
    "550", "280", 
    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
    flashvars, params, attributes);
```

`
And here's my object tag

```
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="550" height="280"     id="dematMultiuploader">
        <param name="movie" value="path/to/swf/file.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="white" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="gedemat/gecco/piece/pieceDocument.create.swf"
            width="350" height="130" id="dematMultiuploader">
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="white" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
            <p>Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or
                Adobe Flash Player version 10.0.0 or greater is not installed.</p>
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"> <img
                src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"
                alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
            </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</noscript>
```

As you can see there's no flashVars param in the Object tag for IE, could that be the problem?

May be IE changed some parameters names for IE11 like crossDomainUrl?

I tryed already to put the flashvars param in the object tag with the crossDomain url but it didn't work.

In firefox and chrome i get this error  :

NetworkError: 404 not found - `http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml`

So they try to load the file directly at the root of the server without any success but it **still works because the crossdomain.xml has already been loaded before this call**. Maybe IE is having trouble finding this file at that particular moment? not taking into account the ones loaded before?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Don't use flash, and for heaven's sake don't use internet explorer ;) http://www.infoworld.com/article/2609519/microsoft-windows/ie11-leaves-flash-media-hanging-on-youtube--more-major-sites.html

Comment: Only kidding, I do see an something though "falshContentID" should probably be "flashContentID"?

Comment: Thanks for your response and the article :) but obviously preventing clients not to use Internet Explorer is not a solution for me...

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! 
in the official documentation of Internet Explorer 11 I found this :

> The preinstalled version of Adobe Flash isn't supported on Internet Explorer 11 running on either Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 with SP1. However, you can still download and install the separate Adobe Flash plug-in.

here's the link to it : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268945.aspx

Since i'm runing on Windows 7 SP1 I reinstalled and everything worked again.

http://get.adobe.com/fr/flashplayer/otherversions/

Answer (score 0):

Removing the  `<noscript>` should help.

Answer (score -1):

falshContentID is not found in the html part. Remove the entire object tag and add
the below code in html area.

```
<div id="falshContentID"></div>
```